# How do i get list of points which satisfy given QPainterPath?

Tags: qt, optimization, qgraphicsview, curve

I have a `QGraphicsView` in my Qt application on which user can draw curves. Curves  consist of `QGraphicsEllipseItem`'s and `QGraphicsPathItem`'s, which connect the adjacent ellipses.

I want to get a list of `QPoint`'s which satisfy the given curve. I tried creating local `QPainterPath` for this procedure which would represent the whole curve and iterating over all the points from it's rectangle to  see which ones satisfy this curve. The code looks like:

```
QPainterPath curvePath = edges[index]->at(0)->path();
qreal left, right, bottom, top;

for(int i=1;i<edges[index]->size();i++)
{
    curvePath.connectPath(edges[index]->at(i)->path());
}

QRectF curveRect = curvePath.boundingRect();
left = curveRect.left();
right = curveRect.right();
top = curveRect.top();
bottom = curveRect.bottom();

for(qreal i = left;i<right;i++)
    for(qreal j = top;j<bottom;j++)
    {
        QPointF pointToCheck(i, j);
        if(curvePath.contains(pointToCheck))
            list.append(pointToCheck);
    }
```

where `edges` is `QList` of `QLists` of `QGraphicsPathItem`'s. It works fine in case of calculations (the point of applying this is to increase precision of calculation), but it really slows down my application since those calculations are made quite often.

Is there more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: `QPainterPath::pointAtPercent` seems to fit your needs

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you want a list of points that make up the entire area enclosed by the path (and if so, then "pointAtPercent" is not going to help you). I did a little bit of digging but didn't find exactly what's needed, but I'm wondering if you painted it onto a black and white image, and then extracted the black pixels, would that give you what you wanted? I'm not sure how much, if any, speed you'd gain, but I would think that the "QPainterPath.contains" method is the killer here.